# How to render a checkbox group with fields from an Entity with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, checkbox, entity, symfony-2.7

I have a **material** table that is related to **items_budget**. The form for **items_budget** needs to list all the registered **material** as a `checkbox` group, and beside each `checkbox`, two `input` fields, for quantity and price. Below is the code block I wrote for rendering this piece:

```
<strong>Materiais</strong>
{% for material in materials %}
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="itemsbudget_material" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[material]" value="{{ material.id }}"> {{ material.name }} - 
        </label>
        <input type="hidden" class="itemsbudget_price_hidden" value="{{ material.price }}"/>
        <input type="text" class="itemsbudget_quantity" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[quantity]" placeholder="Qtd" size="3"/>x - R$
        <input type="text" class="itemsbudget_price" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[price]" value="0" size="3" readonly/>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem I am facing can be seen in the image. Looking at the top-left image, you see I have marked "Material C", filled the quantity, and after submitting the form, as shown in the second image, everything is fine.

But if I do the same with another Material, as it can be seen in the last image of my table, the quantity field is NULL.

What happens here is that only the **first** register in the **material** form is, let's say, "seen". When I say "first register" I mean the lowest *id* in the **material** form, literally the FIRST. If I had deleted the "Material C", then "Material D" would be the first and the quantity field would be seen for it only.

[image]

I have tried to put at the end of each `name` attribute a pair of brackets, but by doing it the page is refreshed and nothing is persisted, nothing happens.

I have tried many different ways to render this. Also, I have tried to create my `material` field as a collection, but I really think this is not the solution because I must get the *id*, *quantity* and *price* entered in the fields. I would need to be able to render something exactly like this with a collection form.

Please I need guidance. If you need any more code I will be happy to update my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The value of quantity field is null, because the name of field is cdg_itemsbudget_type[quantity], the value override by last quantity field which is empty, the name of your field must be array with unique index something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="itemsbudget_quantity" name="cdg_itemsbudget_type[quantity][{{ material.id }}]" placeholder="Qtd" size="3"/>x - R$
```

And then you have array of quantity for each material.